# Binding Source in MediaTimeline

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mediaelement

I am trying to have the mediatimeline bind to a Uri like so:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="myStoryboard">
        <MediaTimeline Storyboard.TargetName="myMediaPlayer"
                       Source="{Binding MediaSource}"
                       RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>

<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource myStoryboard}" />
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>

<Grid>
    <MediaElement x:Name="mymediaPlayer" />
</Grid>
```

However, when I do this, it says that I need to "Must Specify URI." Dispatcher exception. In the viewmodel, I have a property like:

```
    public Uri MediaSource
    {
        get { return _mediaSource; }
        set
        {
            if (_oscilloscopeSource != value)
            {
                _mediaSource= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MediaSource");
            }
        }
    }
```

It seems as though when the media player is loaded, it doesn't read the source from the binding. What gives?

In the constructor, I have:

```
_mediaSource = new Uri(@"C:\someMovie.mov", UriKind.Absolute);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**
Can't get this to work so shooting in the dark now. Does moving the trigger to MediaElement make a difference?

```
<MediaElement x:Name="myMediaPlayer">
    <MediaElement.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource myStoryboard}" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </MediaElement.Triggers>
</MediaElement>
```

I tried this out and it works for me. Possible reasons I can think of.

- Do you have the DataContext set for the UserControl?
- Setting _mediaSource directly won't call OnPropertyChanged since you're not setting the CLR property. Set MediaSource instead.
- Your MediaElement is named mymediaPlayer and not myMediaPlayer as the TargetName. (Typo?)

Except for the MediaElement Name which I changed, my working xaml is identical to yours. This is my full code behind file

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MediaSource = new Uri("C:\\C1.MOV");
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private Uri _mediaSource;
    public Uri MediaSource
    {
        get
        {
            return _mediaSource;
        }
        set
        {
            _mediaSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MediaSource");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: good point, however, it was a typo on my part when I typed it up.

Comment: I noticed that if I change to <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.MouseEnter"> it seems to work when you move your mouse over it. this view model is loaded later on and I'm thinking it has to do with that.. How do I raise my own routed event to trigger it to start?

Comment: @LB: Ok, there goes all my possible reasons :) Hmm, are you using MVVM-light? If I'd be able to reproduce the problem, it might be easier

Comment: No, I wrote my own MVVM Framework.. it's pretty much the same.

Comment: @LB: Have you changed _mediaSource = new Uri(@"C:\someMovie.mov", UriKind.Absolute); to MediaSource = new Uri(@"C:\someMovie.mov", UriKind.Absolute);? Do you run that line the first thing in the ctor.?

Comment: Yeah, seems like the FrameworkElement.Loaded is the problem... It's being called at the point in time when the binding has not occured.

Comment: @LB: Tricky.. Can't trigger on IsLoaded either since it's not a DP. Also, using a DataTrigger to bind against a Property in ViewModel causes a "Freezable" exception with the Storyboard

Comment: @LB: Shooting in the dark now :) Updated my answer, does moving the trigger make any difference?

Comment: No difference at all, it's good. I went an alternative way by building my own MediaElement control and binding to it when needed.